# Magento 2. Searialize Library Questions

Tags: magento2, unserialize

Magento 2 provides some serializers

```
 Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json
 Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Serialize
```

Now they say this

```
    For security reasons, SerializerInterface implementations, such as the 
Json and Serialize classes, should not serialize and unserialize objects.
```

What are those security reasons? Is this a fancy way of saying "We did not manage to implement this" I know there is a Serializer in Symfony that can do objects as well and no "security issues" raised there.

Thanks.